# How much of *Fables* should be read before starting *Fairest*?

Tags: comics, suggested-order, vertigo-comics, fables-comics, fairest

The summary for issue #1 of [*Fairest*](http://www.comixology.com/Fairest-1/digital-comic/JAN120327) says

> Briar Rose, the enchanting Sleeping Beauty, was stolen away by the goblin army in FABLES #107. FAIREST follows her into adventures and misadventures

I haven't read any of [*Fables*](http://www.comixology.com/Fables/comics-series/248). To best enjoy and understand *Fairest*, should I read *Fables* first?  If so, which issues?  Would #107 be enough, or would that be confusing all on its own?  I'm reluctant to purchase and read 107 issues, but if there are a dozen or so key ones that would best set the scene for reading *Fairest*, that would be great.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can jump right into *Fairest* with #1!

*Fables* #107 reminded readers where Briar Rose (Sleeping Beauty) and the Snow Queen have been all this time, but if you know they've been kidnapped by goblins while under the sleeping spell, you've got all the knowledge you need.

Trust me, I tested non-*Fables*-reading peers on this!

Then, as you fall in love with the ladies of *Fairest*, you'll have time to go back and read *Fables* from the beginning at your leisure.

Comment: This answer brought to you by Gregory Lockard, Assistant Editor of "Fairest"